# Discord bot unit conversion command returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I was coding a simple unit conversion command for my discord bot that would convert meters to centimetres. I read over my code several times and couldn't find anything possibly wrong with it, however, when I run the command, it simply returns "undefined" for the result value. I also made a point to double check the scope of my code blocks to make sure all the variables are properly accessible.

Code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'convert ')) {
        
        let content = message.content.replace(prefix + 'convert ', '');
        content.split(' ');

        let value = content[0];
        let firstUnit = content[1];
        let convertedUnit = content[3];
        let result;
        let description;
        let embedFormula;

        if (firstUnit === 'm' && convertedUnit === 'cm') {
            const formula = (inputValue) => {
                return inputValue * 100;    
            }
            
            result = formula(value);
            description = `${value} m to cm = **${result} cm**`;
            embedFormula = '`Multiply the length value by 100`';    
        }

        const conversionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Unit Conversion')
        .setDescription(description)
        .setColor('#F942FF')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Formula', value: embedFormula }
        )

        message.delete();
        message.channel.send(conversionEmbed);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

The command runs when the user types "_convert 1 m to cm" (1 can of course be swapped with any number).

Is there anything missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems your `if (firstUnit === 'm' && convertedUnit === 'cm')` is evaluating to `false`. Have you tried debugging the values of `firstUnit` and `convertedUnit`?

Comment: @Phil Aha! Yes that was the problem, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Phil I don't really know what the problem was, however, after trying it out it a bit it seems I've come across another problem, any input over 10 cm returns undefined for some reason

Answer (score 1):

`content.split()` won't edit existing variables:

```js
let content = 'Hello!';
content.split();

console.log(content); // Still 'Hello!'
console.log(content[0]); // This just gets the first character
```

So instead of this:

```js
let content = message.content.replace(prefix + 'convert ', '');
content.split(' ');
```

You should do this:

```js
let content = message.content.replace(prefix + 'convert ', '').split(' ');
```